# How to install and use F# Powerpack in Mono?

Tags: f#, mono, gac, powerpack

I need to install use [F# powerpack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/).
I use mono version 2.10.2 on Mac.

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.2 (tarball Mon Apr 18 09:14:01 MDT 2011)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           normal
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notification:  kqueue
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          debugger softdebug 
        LLVM:          yes(2.9svn-mono)
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
```

### Installation.

1. Download the powerpack zip file from [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/40168).
2. Unzip the file to directory `~/bin`.
3. Add the `~/bin/FSharpPowerPack-1.9.9.9/bin` to the PATH. I also add it to the MONO_PATH just in case. (I'm not sure if this is necessary or not)
4. For the dlls in the `~/bin/FSharpPowerPack-1.9.9.9/bin/gac`, use the command `sudo gacutil -i <ALL_THE_FILES_IN_DLL>.dll`

### Using the powerpack

I tested with the sample code in [this page](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). I name it linq.fs

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
let adderExpr = <@ fun i -> i + 1 @>.ToLinqExpression()
let adder = <@ fun i -> i + 1 @>.Compile()
```

### Questions

1. I got errors with `fsc linq.fs /r:FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll`. What might be wrong?

   /Users/smcho/Desktop/fs/powerpack/linq.fs(1,38): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'ToLinqExpression' is not defined

   /Users/smcho/Desktop/fs/powerpack/linq.fs(2,34): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Compile' is not defined
2. Do I need to install all the dll with `gacutil -i`? Or, just appending the dll path to the PATH/MONO_PATH environment variable is just good enough?

Comment: You left out one of the most important details -- what version of Mono?

Comment: Does your test code `open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq`?

Comment: @Joel Mueller : Yes it does, I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your installation procedure seems to be correct (just unzip and install using `gacutil -i`).  I think there is just a minor issue with the sample - the `ToLinqExpression` extension method is available in a module that needs to be explicitly opened, so your file should be:

**EDIT** The right module name is actually `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation`:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

let adderExpr = <@ fun i -> i + 1 @>.ToLinqExpression()
let adder = <@ fun i -> i + 1 @>.Compile()
```

Comment: I stumbled on this recently too. Was this changed in 2.0?

Comment: I got `/Users/smcho/Desktop/fs/powerpack/linq.fs(1,28): error FS0039: The namespace 'QuotationEvaluator' is not defined` together with the original error message. I'm not sure I had to run `gacuitl -i` for the dlls not in the gac directory.

Comment: @prosseek - Sorry, I got the module name wrong (should be `QuotationEvaluation`! Adding files to the GAC is not strictly necessary, you can just reference them with a full path and them copy them to the output location (same directory as your application).

Comment: @Daniel - I don't know exactly, but I also think it must have changed. The feature is a bit limited, so my guess is that the F# team doesn't want to overly emphasize it...

Comment: Thanks it works. BWT, I got some reference related error with the dll, so I asked another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207270/referencing-net-dll-when-compiliationwith-mono

Comment: `gacutil -i Error: Option -i takes 1 argument`