# Referencing .NET dll when compiliation(with mono)

Tags: .net, mono, reference

I asked a question to install F# powerpack and use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206406/how-to-install-and-use-f-powerpack-in-mono).

```
error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll' in any of
 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib/mono/2.0
 /Users/smcho/Desktop/fs/powerpack
 /Users/smcho/smcho/bin/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin
```

When I run this command `fsc linq.fs /r:FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll`, I got this error message with mono.

It seems that with `/r:`, the mono F# compiler seems to find the dll in

1. /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib/mono/2.0 <-- mono directory
2. /Users/smcho/smcho/bin/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin <-- F# directory
3. /Users/smcho/Desktop/fs/powerpack <-- current directory.

However, I don't want to copy all the dll's in the current directory, is there any way to let mono F# or C# compiler know where to find the dll other than those two directory?

It seems that MONO_PATH and `gacutil -i` is for finding the dll at runtime, not compile time.

### ADDED

`/I:` option is available with `fsc` compiler.

```
fsc linq.fs /I:/bin/FSharpPowerPack-1.9.9.9/bin/gac /r:FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use

-r:/full/path/to/the/reference/assembly

?  (You are right that gacutil is for runtime assemblies, whereas -r is for design-time reference assemblies, which may or may not be the same.)

Comment: For the F# compiler, I think there's also a `-I` include path option maybe.